# Implementing TAP around WMI

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to improve my skills with the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx), by writing simple task-based wrappers around some WMI methods:

```
void Main()
{
    var driveLetter = "E:";
    var query = string.Format("select * from Win32_Volume WHERE DriveLetter = '{0}'", driveLetter);
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
    foreach (ManagementObject volume in searcher.Get()) 
    {
        // LINQPad Progress Bar
        var pb = new Util.ProgressBar("Formatting:");
        var progress = new Progress<int>(pct => pb.Percent = pct);
        pb.Dump();

        var task = volume.InvokeMethodAsync("Format", new object[] { "FAT", false, 16384, "", false }, progress);
        var result = task.Result; // or var result = await task;
        result.Dump();
    }
}

static class ManagementObjectExtensions
{
    public static Task<object> InvokeMethodAsync(this ManagementObject managementObject, string methodName, object[] args)
    {
        return InvokeMethodAsync(managementObject, methodName, args, null);
    }

    public static Task<object> InvokeMethodAsync(this ManagementObject managementObject, string methodName, object[] args, IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        var watcher = new ManagementOperationObserver();
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        object returnValue = null;
        watcher.ObjectReady += (obj, a) => returnValue = a.NewObject.GetPropertyValue("ReturnValue");
        watcher.Completed += (obj, a) => tcs.TrySetResult(returnValue);
        if (progress != null) 
        {
            watcher.Progress += (obj, a) => progress.Report(a.Current);
        }

        managementObject.InvokeMethod(watcher, methodName, args);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

So far, this seems to work, but it seems almost too easy, and I keep thinking there have to some gotchas I need to watch out for. Am I doing this right?

Comment: You have methods named `InvokeMethodAsync` but I don't see the `async` modifier on the signatures.  Maybe you had it at one time and that's why you've commented the await task line.  Other than that, interesting bit of code.

Comment: @RickDavin Thanks. That's true, `Main` could have been declared as `async void`, then that line could have been modified to `await task`. But `InvokeMethodAsync` doesn't need to be async since I'm not awaiting anything inside it.

Comment: I'm not really sure but I think  that `watcher.ObjectReady` return for each value so you must be sure that your query return a single value (like in your example).